# Getting a conflict between jquery.simplemodal and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

In my asp.net mvc 3 application, I have a popup animation which uses jquery.simplemodal plugin. Here is the code responsible for the animation

```
$.modal(data, {
containerId: 'popupdiv',
opacity: 5,
autoResize: true,
overlayCss: { backgroundColor: "#000" },
onShow: function () {
    initSwitchToLatest()
},
onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn(0, function () {
        var h = $("#popupdiv").height();
        var w = $("#popupdiv").width();
        var l = $("#popupdiv").css("left");
        var t = $("#popupdiv").css("top");
        dialog.container.fadeIn('fast', function () {
            if ($.browser.msie) {
                $('.popup').css('behavior', 'none');
            }
            $('#popupdiv').css('opacity', 0);
            dialog.data.height(0);
            dialog.data.width(0);
            $(".popup").width(0);
            $("#popupdiv").css("left", popup_mouse_x + "px");
            $("#popupdiv").css("top", popup_mouse_y + "px");
            dialog.data.show();
            $(".popup").animate({ "width": w, "height": "auto" }, 500);
            dialog.data.animate({ "height": h, "width": w }, 500);
            $("#popupdiv").animate({ "left": l, "top": t, "opacity": 1 }, 500, function () {
            $("#loading-mask").show();
            if ($.browser.msie) {
            $('.popup').css('behavior', 'url(../../../Scripts/PIE.htc)');
            }
            ReplacePopupContents($("#popupContentUrl").val());
            });
        });
    });
  }
});
```

Now I am trying to use jquery-mobile scrolling effect, but if I call these two plugins together like this :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: $.modal is not a function
```

And the popup animation won't show up.

PS : This error shows up only when I call the second plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to include the jquery file before the simple modal file. like this

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this way I lost the scrolling effect

Comment: did you check with firebug whether the files are included? if u have still problem try to use the keyword jQuery instead of '$' if you thing there is conflict

Comment: I got the same thing, TypeError: jQuery.modal is not a function. And I checked with firebug, the files are included